# Setting Default Options for Backbone Collections

Tags: backbone.js, backbone.js-collections

I have a Backbone Collection like so:

```
var ThreadCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  url: '/api/rest/thread/getList'
});
var myCollection = new ThreadCollection();
```

And then I'm fetching it from the server using the data object to append the query parameters (so in this case it comes out '/api/rest/thread/getList?userId=487343')

```
myCollection.fetch({
  data: {
    userId: 487343
  }
})
```

There are other parameters that I may want to use instead of userId (groupId, orgId, etc) but I'd ideally define the data parameters upon initialization and from then on be able to run fetch() without specifying. Something like this:

```
var myCollection = new ThreadCollection({
  data: {
    userId: 487343
  }
});

myCollection.fetch()
```

but it doesn't work. Does anyone know if there's a way to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way is to define a custom `fetch` method on your collection which calls the super `fetch` method with some overridable defaults:

```
var ThreadCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    url: '/api/rest/thread/getList',
    fetch: function(options) {
        return Backbone.Collection.prototype.fetch.call(this, _.extend({
            data: {
                userId: 48743
            }
        }, options));
    }
});

var myCollection = new ThreadCollection();

myCollection.fetch();
```

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I was thinking of and works great!